# Word Template : Executing VBA macro on a graphical button click

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I've created a VBA Macro for word template and I want to associate it to a button(Graphics button, Not keyboard buttons).There are basically two ways to create a macro :

1) Using macro recorder

2) Using VBA for application to write macro from scratch

But I found several issues with these ways :

I tried First one, What I want is to execute a macro on a button onclick event. but in that I am not getting how to assign that macro to that button.

For second option I tried following procedure :

Goto VB by pressing Alt + F11.
On the Tools menu, click References.
Select the reference for Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility.
Insert a new module, and then add the following code example.

```
 Sub Test()

'Add a command button to a new document
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim shp As Word.InlineShape
Set doc = Documents.Add

Set shp = doc.Content.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1")
shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "Click Here"

'Add a procedure for the click event of the inlineshape
'**Note: The click event resides in the This Document module
Dim sCode As String
sCode = "Private Sub " & shp.OLEFormat.Object.Name & "_Click()" & vbCrLf & _
        "   MsgBox ""You Clicked the CommandButton""" & vbCrLf & _
        "End Sub"
doc.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisDocument").CodeModule.AddFromString sCode

End Sub
```

This is the code for macro creation through Vb.But here error is coming in secondlast line of code.

Can anyone suggest me how to get an executable macro on a button click? Am I doing any mistakes in above code?

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing? Is it related to security of VBA project model? I am able to run this code from word vba and the button gets associated with the code.

Comment: The Error related to above code is solved now.Actually we need to enable Vb application and extensibility through Tools -> References ->  Microsoft Visual basic Apllication and extensibility. This is because by default the VBA macro thing is disabled in Microsoft word.

Comment: U can find more help from this link to enable your VBA support to MS- word http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282830

Comment: Does that mean, your question is answered?

Comment: Nope.I am still not getting how to execute a macro on button click.

Comment: Your code works without any error when I paste & run it under a new word document. What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: i am not getting error for above code now.Basically what I want to do is i want to create a button on word and I want a macro with richtextbox to be created when I clicks on that button. I have created a macro but i want to call macro from this button.So I am not getting how to call that function.Can anyonw help me out.

Comment: You dont need to associate the macro with the button. With the sample code above, it creates a button in the word doc, clicking on which it shows a msgbox (without your code actually mapping the click event of button to the method). Click on the button to see if it shows the msgbox. If not this, what are you looking for?

Comment: I am getting a msgbox on button clicking.But I wanted a macro that can  create a richtextbox to be called on buttonClick. Well, I got the solution from the answer given below by Braim.

Answer (score 3):

For office 2010 that I have:

1.Macros can be assigned to buttons that will show up in top-left corner of your window (Quick Access Toolbar) 
When you create a macro, it asks if you want to assign it to keyboard or Button where you can select button

2.You can add a `command button` or any other control that will run a code when you click it. To do so first you have to add 'Command Button' to your ribbon so that you can create button in your page. To add it you can click on Office button, go to `Options`, then go to `Customize Ribbon` and then select `All commands` from `Choose commands from` drop down list. find the `Command Button` and add it somewhere to you ribbon. You may have to create a custom tab in your ribbon. 
When you have the button in your ribbon, then you can add button to your page and after adding the ribbon double-click on it, and you can write code in button's event handler. You can copy & paste your Macro code there or call the macro using `call` command
[image: How to add a button and call a Macro]

Comment: Thank you braim.I got the command button. But can you please eloborate  how to call a macro from microsoft word object (Window which gets open  When I click on Command Button ) ??

Comment: if macro is defined in the document, then you can simply call it using it's name e.g.
call Macro1

Comment: Thank a lot..This part is working properly. But macro runs only when u clicks on run option in VB.Is there any way to run macro on onClick event of command button on word itself (I mean without opening VBA; just to click on run)?

Comment: use 'call' command with the macro name to run the macro e.g. 'call Macro1'. You can see how I called the macro in the attached screenshot

Comment: I did it in same way but i am not getting the functionality when I clicking on command button from wordDoc. Same thing I am getting through open VBA -> click run.I Dont want that the user open VBA everytime just to execute my code in my template.

Comment: I directly want him to click on command button on word for achieving required functionality.

Comment: if you call the Macro using call Macro command, then user does not need to open VBA or run macro. It works in sample Word file I created. What error you are getting? Can you share the code you have in button's Click function?

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your issue with the command button showing the VB code when clicking instead of actually running - make sure you are not in Design Mode. Look under the Developer tab on your ribbon and make sure Design Mode is not highlighted.

Comment: Hey thank you.But problem is solved now..I will upload the solution soon.okay